# HOW TO Pass Values Between Multiple Select Boxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to pass selected item from one multiple combo box to another to  multi combobox.

How do I do that? is there any example for that?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <SELECT NAME="possible" SIZE"10" MULTIPLE>
    <OPTION VALUE="New Red Corvette">New Red Corvette</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Vintage Red Corvette">Vintage Red Corvette</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Old Red Corvette">Old Red Corvette</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
  <SELECT NAME="wishlist" SIZE="10" MULTIPLE>
    <OPTION VALUE="Old Red Jalopy">Old Red Jalopy</OPTION>
  </SELECT>


<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Add to wishlist"
       ONCLICK="MyMoveItem(possible,wishlist);">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Remove from wishlist" 
       ONCLICK="MyMoveItem(wishlist,possible);">

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Can you share with us, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: What does your `MyMoveItem()` function look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#b1").click(function(){
  $("#s2").append( $("#s1 option:selected"))
})

$("#b2").click(function(){
  $("#s1").append( $("#s2 option:selected"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SELECT id="s1" NAME="possible" SIZE"10" MULTIPLE>
    <OPTION VALUE="New Red Corvette">New Red Corvette</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Vintage Red Corvette">Vintage Red Corvette</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Old Red Corvette">Old Red Corvette</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
  <SELECT id="s2" NAME="wishlist" SIZE="10" MULTIPLE>
    <OPTION VALUE="Old Red Jalopy">Old Red Jalopy</OPTION>
  </SELECT>


<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" id="b1" VALUE="Add to wishlist"
       ONCLICK="MyMoveItem(possible,wishlist);">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" id="b2" VALUE="Remove from wishlist" 
       ONCLICK="MyMoveItem(wishlist,possible);">
```

Comment: There is no need for the `remove()` as jQuery realizes the element already exists and it moves it instead of cloning it.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this solution also handles multiple selected items holding the CTRL key.